# Call data from other sheet using ActiveX button and calculate its average

Tags: excel, vba

i have numbers of data in sheet2. for example B4=2, B5=4 and C4=6, C5=4. I want to use the ActiveX button to call the data from sheet2 and calculate its average in sheet1 by clicking on the ActiveX button. Can you help how to use the VBA code in this problem?
Thank you

this code has data is not related to the post, but the idea is the same

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`

`Dim AVG As Integer`

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate`

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.average(Range("A1:A2"))`

`AVG = Application.WorksheetFunction.average(Range("A1:A2"))`

`MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value`

`End Sub`

i want to create a button where if i put in a name, for example Jan13, the button in sheet1 will calculate its average based on range B3:B10 on sheet 2. and the msgBox will come up with the result

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: yes, i tried and i also did some research but i really cannot do it.plus, i really am a beginner at vba. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you please post some code? (not my -1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This it should solve your problem.

```
Public Sub Average()

Dim AVG As String
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
' Range here to calculate average of is A1 to A20
AVG = Application.Average(Range("A1:A20"))
' This is where the result of the average be displayed
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value = AVG 

End Sub
```

Also you don't need an ActiveX button. Just use a normal button and assign this macro to it.

Comment: @Mohd Faiq Farhan, If you are satisfied with the answer don't forget to accept it as your answer.

Comment: i put the range= Range("D4:D9").Value
but it says "compile error, invalid use of property"

Comment: I just checked with your Range("D4:D9"), its working fine.
You just have to replace A1:A20 with D4:D9.
Hope you are doing this only.

Upload the code that you are using after modifying.